# What are the security risks to enabling editing in Excel and Word, if macros are disabled?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, security, microsoft-office, macros

I'm using Office Professional Plus 2016. I often receive Excel spreadsheets and Word docs from clients and need to make small changes before sending them back. Assuming that my macro settings are set to "Disable all macros with notification," what are the remaining security risks of clicking on Enable Editing in the PROTECTED VIEW bar? If there are any, what can be done to mitigate them?

Comment: You can embed JavaScript into a Word or Excel document.  So even if you disable macros, if you recieve files from unknown sources, you can still be infected with malware.  There is then of course the files that claim to be Word documents are but are actually an executable.

Comment: try this: https://superuser.com/questions/642419/how-can-you-find-out-if-xlsx-and-docx-files-are-safe-to-open